# problem with intergating facebook & twitter for iPhone in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am being using facebook & twitter in my application where user post comment on facebook & twitter . I have facing problem while using facebook i have used session so once user login
he is not getting option for logout. he will continued posting comment .

And for twitter : How will  i create application in twitter for my application .

so please help me to find this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For facebook, you can call your session to logout:

```
if (self.session.isConnected) {
    [self.session logout];
}
```

For twitter, you first must register your application with twitter, then you can use some library to support you like [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine), which we are using for our applications